# upload multiple photos for one product and get it using nodejs (typeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm using typeScript in my express backend project , and i want to post multiple photo  in one product and then show it in the productDetail page .. any help please
i finished to upload just one photo but i need to upload multiple files
this is all api for manage (get , post) product queries !! i need help please :'(

```
///product interface
export class Product {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
  pictures: string[];
  picture: string;
  description: string;
  owner: Provider;
  type: Categorie;
}

export class Categorie {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
}

//ProductSchema
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  quantity: { type: Number, required: true, default: 1 },
  type: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Categorie', required: true },
  owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  picture: { type: String, required: false },
  pictures: [{ type: String, required: false }]
});

const categorieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  icon: { type: String },
});
productSchema.set('timestamps', true);
categorieSchema.set('timestamps', true);

const productModel = mongoose.model<Product & mongoose.Document>('Product', productSchema);
const categorieModel = mongoose.model<Categorie & mongoose.Document>('Categorie', categorieSchema);

const marketmodel = {
  productModel,
  categorieModel,
};


//Service for creating a new Product with one pictures
import { isValidObjectId } from 'mongoose';
import HttpException from '../exceptions/HttpException';
import { Product, Categorie } from '../interfaces/product.interface';
import { User } from '../interfaces/users.interface';
import marketmodel from '../models/product.model';
import { isEmptyObject } from '../utils/util';
import fs from 'fs';
import { Provider } from '../interfaces/provider.interface';
import userModel from '../models/users.model';

class ProductService {
  public products = marketmodel.productModel;
  public categories = marketmodel.categorieModel;

  public async createProduct(productData): Promise<Product> {
    if (isEmptyObject(productData)) throw new HttpException(400, "can't create empty Product");
    const provider: Provider = await userModel.findById(productData.owner);
    if (provider.role != 'provider') {
      throw new HttpException(400, 'Only providers can add products!');
    }
    const product = new this.products(productData);
    return await product.save();
  }
  public async getProduct(id: string): Promise<Product> {
const prod: Product = await this.products.findById(id).populate('owner', 'companyName slug profilePicture').populate('type', 'name').lean();
return prod;
```

}

```
//controller addProduct

import { nextDay } from 'date-fns';
import { NextFunction, Response } from 'express';
import HttpException from '../exceptions/HttpException';
import { RequestWithFile, RequestWithUser } from '../interfaces/auth.interface';
import { Product, Categorie } from '../interfaces/product.interface';
import { Provider } from '../interfaces/provider.interface';
import ProductService from '../services/product.service';

class ProductController {
  public productService = new ProductService();

  public createProduct = async (req: RequestWithFile, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const provider: Provider = req.user as Provider;
      const productData = req.body;
      productData.owner = provider._id;
      
      if (req.file) {
        productData.picture = req.file.path.split('/').splice(1).join('/');
      }

      const product: Product = await this.productService.createProduct(productData);
      res.status(201).json({ data: product, message: 'Created Product' });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
 public getProduct = async (req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
try {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const provider = req.user;
  const product = await this.productService.getProduct(id);
  res.status(200).json({ data: { product } });
} catch (error) {
  next(error);
}
```

};
//route and multer middlware

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import Route from '../interfaces/routes.interface';
import multer from 'multer';
import fs from 'fs';
import shortid from 'shortid';
import ProductController from '../controllers/product.controller';
import authMiddleware from '../middlewares/auth.middleware';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    let path: string;
    if (file.mimetype.includes('image')) {
      path = 'uploads/products/';
      if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
      }
      cb(null, path);
    }
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const a = file.originalname.split('.');
    cb(null, `${shortid.generate()}-${Date.now()}.${a[a.length - 1]}`);
  },
});
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ storage: storage });

class ProductRoute implements Route {
  public path = '/products';
  public router = Router();
  public productController = new ProductController();
  constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

 private initializeRoutes() {
   this.router.get(`${this.path}/all`, this.productController.getAllProducts);
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/product/new`, authMiddleware, uploadMiddleware.array('file'), this.productController.createProduct);

 this.router.get(`${this.path}/product/:id `, this.productController.getProduct);
```

Comment: any help plz ;/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).